# Нужны ли тут запятые?

Tags: орфография

Что-то я засомневалась, нужны тут запятые или нет: "Мы(,) как могли(,) отремонтировали..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет под рукой Розенталя, чтобы поискать подобный пример. Рассуждаем, исходя из правил. Если "как могли" - придаточное предложение или сравнительный оборот - запятые ставим. Если обстоятельство образа действия - нет. Если фразеологизм - нет. Я бы не поставила. Использую любимый пример замены/подстановки - отремонтировали старательно. Т.е этот оборот воспринимается мной как цельный. С другой стороны, может автор совсем не это имел в виду? Тогда бы я написала понятнее: как могли, так и отремонтировали.