# Согласование времен в русском языке

Tags: грамматика

В качестве примера приведу отрывок из рассказа Ю. Яковлева "Временный жилец"

> Лелька сидит на крыльце и штопает чулок. Она поленилась разыскать грибок и штопает прямо на коленке. Осторожно, чтобы не уколоться, она то опускает, то поднимает блестящее острие иглы. Розовая коленка постепенно скрывается под штопкой, похожей на листок тетради в клеточку.
>
> ... Когда девочка поднимает глаза, перед ней стоят Федор Федорович, председатель поселкового Совета, и незнакомый военный. Лицо Федора Федоровича коричневое, испеченное на солнце. А военный - бледнолицый. Он еще не загорел на степном солнышке. В одной руке он держит чемодан, в другой, согнутой в локте, - шинель.
>
> - Здравствуй, хозяйка, - говорит Федор Федорович.
> - Здрасте, - отзывается Лелька и встает со ступеньки.
>
> Она не выпускает из рук иглу, и короткая нитка не дает ей выпрямиться. Одна нога в чулке, а другая безо всего, голая. Косичка снова соскользнула с плеча. Вид у Лельки, вероятно, смешной, потому что военный отворачивается в сторону, чтобы скрыть улыбку.
>
> - А где мать? - спрашивает Федор Федорович.
>
> Он спрашивает, а военный молчит. Стоит за Федором Федоровичем и из-за плеча смотрит на Лельку. Девочке кажется, что он разглядывает ее заштопанную коленку. Ей хочется прикрыть коленку, но сарафан короткий.
>
> - Мама пошла в сельпо, - отвечает Лелька и краснеет.
>
> Иголка выскальзывает из рук и, поблескивая, раскачивается на нитке.
>
> - Ну, вот что, - говорит Федор Федорович, - ты, конечно, слыхала про снаряды?
>
> Лелька мотнула головой. Она слышала, что в степи, неподалеку от поселка, обнаружили завалившуюся землянку со снарядами - артпогребок. Артпогребок был брошен немцами много лет назад. А теперь нашелся. Говорят, что он заминирован.
>
> - Так вот, - продолжает председатель поселкового Совета, - прибыли саперы обезвреживать. Солдат мы поместили в школе, а командира...
> - Федор Федорович кивает на военного и слегка подталкивает его вперед, - а командира мы хотим определить к вам.
>
> Лелька снова кивает.
>
> - Места у вас много. Думаю, мать возражать не будет?
> - Ага, - соглашается Лелька, будто она заранее знает, что мама не будет возражать.
> - Тогда знакомьтесь. Лейтенант... - Федор Федорович вопросительно смотрит на военного.
> - Шура, - подсказывает он.
> - Лейтенант Шура... А это Лелька.
> - Очень приятно, - говорит лейтенант, а Лелька снова краснеет. Она ничего не может с собой поделать. Краска стыда по малейшему поводу заливает ее лицо, обдает его жаром и отравляет Лельке жизнь.
>
> Девочка покраснела, будущий жилец отвернул лицо, чтобы скрыть улыбку, а Федор Федорович почесал седую щетину, которая проступает, как соль, на его запеченной, коричневой щеке.
>
> - Сейчас мы пойдем в степь, - распоряжается председатель. - Вещи лейтенант оставит здесь. А придет мать, ты предупреди ее.
>
> Лейтенант Шура подходит к крыльцу и вопросительно смотрит на Лельку:
>
> - Можно здесь поставить?
> - Ага! - кивает Лелька и закусывает губу, будто губа - виновница ее смятения.
>
> Лейтенант поставил на крыльцо зеленый чемодан, положил на него шинель.
>
> - Пошли! - почти скомандовал Федор Федорович.
>
> И они зашагали к калитке.
>
> Когда неожиданные гости ушли, Лелька облегченно вздохнула и опустилась на ступеньку, согретую солнцем. Первым делом она поджала ноги и прикрыла подолом сарафана заштопанную коленку.
>
> Рядом, на ступеньке, стоял чемодан, а на нем лежала сложенная пополам шинель. Шинель была серой и шершавой. От нее пахло валенками. На погонах весело поблескивали звездочки - по две на каждом.
>
> Лелька покосилась на чужие вещи и быстро стянула с ноги заштопанный чулок. Будто вместе с чемоданом и шинелью в доме остался жилец и его насмешливые глаза продолжали рассматривать Лельку, отыскивая, над чем бы посмеяться. Лелькин дом маленький, но двухэтажный. Вернее, на чердаке папа при жизни сделал небольшую комнатку "для гостей". Когда приезжал дядя Митя, его помещали на втором этаже. С тех пор гостей не было. Но за комнатой сохранилось название - "для гостей". Вот туда-то Лелька и решила определить жильца.

Вопрос в следующем. Скажите пожалуйста, возможно ли такое сочетание времен в одном повествовании, если девочка сначала "сидИТ и штопаЕТ", а через какое-то время она "подумаЛА, мотнуЛА головой, покраснеЛА"?

Мне в сочинении указали на "прыгающие времена", а я никак не могу найти правило на этот случай. Подскажите пожалуйста, в приведенном выше примере все верно? Или в рассказе Ю. Яковлева тоже "времена прыгают"? И является ли это стилистической или речевой ошибкой? И возможно ли сочетание времен в одном рассказе, если это подчеркивает какие-то действия или делает акценты на чем-нибудь?

Наверное, сразу нужно было это сделать, но я постеснялась. Вот текст:

//====
Был погожий летний денек. Шел четвертый год войны, маленькому Лёне тогда уже исполнилось шесть лет. Это был белобрысый, любопытный, худющий мальчишка, с веснушчатым носом. Большие, голубые глаза его с интересом, пытливо наблюдали за миром. Да, вокруг война, но мир от этого не становится менее прекрасным. Также интересны почки на деревьях, также красив покрытый инеем лес, также тепло греет солнышко в погожие дни, в речке рыба клюет не хуже, чем в мирное время, да и вообще… Когда началась война, Лене было всего три года. Он и не помнил, что значит жить в «мирное» время. Для него пока все время было одинаковое и другого он еще не знал.

В деревне Чубковичи, что недалеко от города Брянска, расположился штаб немецких войск. Изба бабы Ани самая большая и зажиточная в деревне. У Лёни было шесть братьев, баба Аня была богатой на сыновей. Трое из них ушли на фронт, как и дед Василий, двое работали в городе, на производстве. В деревне остались только сама хозяйка, ее отец, дед Захар, десятилетний Толик и шестилетний Леня. Толик, наравне со взрослыми работал не покладая рук. Пас корову, ходил в лес за дровами, таскал воду, ворошил сено, помогал, как мог. Маленький Лёня тоже не ленился, но природное любопытство часто отвлекало его от тяжелой работы. Пошел на сеновал разгребать сухую траву, увидел ящерку, решил поймать. А работа не сделана, да и ящерка убежала. За такое ему часто доставалось и от старшего брата, и от деда Захара.

В тот день мальчишки где-то нашли снаряд. Боевой, наверное. Страшный и такой притягательный. Так хотелось его разглядеть как следует, потрогать, и, если повезет, разобрать и посмотреть из чего же он сделан. Вокруг необычной находки собралось пять или шесть пацанят. Маленькому Лёне не видно. Мальчишки так плотно обступили находку, не подобраться. Каждый говорит, что знает, делится, советует. Кто-то уже принес инструменты, сейчас будут смотреть что там! Предательские слезы уже готовы набежать на глаза и позорно скатиться солеными дорожками по худеньким грязным щекам. Что же такое? Почему самое интересное всегда без меня? Как же хочется, ну, хоть одним глазком посмотреть из чего же сделан боевой снаряд. Он такой огромный, тяжелый даже на вид. Пахнет так незнакомо, опасностью, тревогой… смертью?

— Ленька! А ну, подь сюды! — дед Захар зовет. Ну, что же еще ему надо? Я, ведь все сделал, что он просил, подмел, кур покормил, воды принес. — Ленька, надо бревно распилить, подь, подержишь пилу! А ну, быстренько!

Деда Захара ослушаться чревато. Если бы дело было только в огромном дрыне, что пускает в воспитательных целях дед, можно было бы и не ходить. Но ведь дед пустит в ход тяжелую артиллерию, расскажет мамане, и тогда в ход пойдет ухват. А ухват тяжелый. Как и маманина рука. Так что, надо идти.

Смахивая предательскую соль со щек, и ругая, так не вовремя подвернувшееся для распила бревно, Леня потрусил на двор. Не успел он добежать до калитки, как улочку потряс страшный, оглушительный взрыв. Снаряд действительно был боевой. И он взорвался.

Взрывной волной маленького Леню опрокинуло на землю. Медленно, как в плохом кино, Леня пытается подняться на руках. Всего трясет, тело непослушное, в ушах гул, ничего не слышно. Дед Захар выскакивает из калитки, его рот открывается в беззвучном крике, для Лени все происходит в гулком вязком тумане. Сильные руки подхватывают мальчика подмышки, но он все равно успевает одним глазом увидеть страшное, кровавое месиво на дороге, в которое превратились его друзья. Перед тем как спасительная темнота поглотила его, он успел подумать, что если бы не бревно, он мог быть там, на дороге…
//====

Comment: >> *Мне в сочинении указали на "прыгающие времена"* Интересно бы посмотреть хотя бы фрагмент

Comment: *Наверное, сразу нужно было это сделать, но я постеснялась.* - и совершенно напрасно. Мы же вам помогаем,  а не Юрию Яковлеву. Сейчас посмотрю, что у вас там за проблемы. В конце концов здесь опытные преподаватели есть. Людмила, это "ваш клиент".

Answer (score 2):

В русском языке нет обязательного грамматического требования на использование каких-то конкретных грамматических форм. Все решается по ситуации, по контексту. Ошибки лексические, даже грамматические, конечно, возможны, но в основном это касается использования неличных глагольных форм (включая причастия и деепричастия), реже - сложноподчиненных конструкций. В сложносочиненных предложениях такую ошибку вообще сделать трудно. А когда речь идет вообще о разных предложениях - грамматика никак не может быть нарушена подобными приемами.

Иногда школьные преподаватели абсолютизируют стилистическую рекомендацию писать "в одном времени", но это неправильно, она имеет сугубо конкретное поле действия: не перескакивать с оного времени на другое ***без надобности***. Типа "мальчик сидит и пел". Но такое реально встречается только у совсем уж неопытных авторов или иностранцев.

Вам бы лучше выложить свои тексты, сочинение, в котором "указали на", а не рассказ какой-то.

> если девочка сначала "сидИТ и штопаЕТ", а через какое-то время она
>   "подумаЛА, мотнуЛА головой, покраснеЛА"?

Здесь это стилистический прием. Сначала повествование идет как бы в статике, что-то вроде описания сцены перед началом действия. "Застывшее настоящее". Потом уже пошло собственно действие. В русском языке нет подходящих временн**ы**х форм для выражения подобного только что совершенного действия, используется прошедшее время.

Оправданность приема можно обсуждать, но никакого вопиющего лексического нарушения я не вижу. Вот когда подобный переход с одного грамматического времени на другое не оправдан контекстом, возможна ошибка. Но все равно надо очень внимательно смотреть, как и почему времена, как вы назвали, "прыгают".

> Подскажите пожалуйста, в приведенном выше примере все верно? Или в рассказе Ю. Яковлева тоже "времена прыгают"?

Ну в каком-то смысле да, "прыгают", но это никак нельзя признать ошибкой.

Answer (score 1):

Это вопрос хорошего стиля (или единства стиля): он может специально продумываться рассказчиком, а может и отсутствовать, если автор больше увлечён содержанием, которое стремится донести, и не оглядывается с пристрастием на написанное. На мой взгляд, "переключения" возможны, но они не должны быть разбросаны настолько, чтобы возникали недоуменные вопросы; для них должно быть сюжетное основание (смена настроения персонажа или общей тональности рассказа при каком-нибудь повороте; вставка рассказа от имени персонажа в настоящем времени и т. п.). Заглянул сейчас в первое, что вспомнилось из написанного в настоящем времени: рассказ Чехова "Хамелеон" - он весь выдержан в едином стиле настоящего же времени.

Answer (score 1):

> Большие, голубые глаза его

Скорее всего определения - неоднородные, запятая не нужна.

> Также интересны почки на деревьях, также красив покрытый инеем лес, также тепло греет солнышко в погожие дни, в речке рыба клюет не хуже, чем в мирное время, да и вообще…

"Так же" - раздельно во всех случаях. Если конечно смысл "так же, как и без войны". А с "также" у вас список получается: "а также лес, почки и прочее".

> В деревне Чубковичи, что недалеко от города Брянска, расположился штаб немецких войск

Это не ошибка, но тут скорее всего "располагался". Как данность, а не как событие.

> помогал, как мог

Мне запятая непонятна. 
Подробности - [Нужны ли тут запятые?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4859)

> хотелось его разглядеть как следует, потрогать, и, если повезет, разобрать и посмотреть из чего же он сделан.

одна из двух запятых вокруг первого "и" - лишняя. Скорее всего - первая.

Это не все, только то, что не мог не отметить.

Теперь по сути.

> Мальчишки так плотно обступили находку, не подобраться. Каждый говорит, что знает, делится, советует.

Да, переход от повествования в прошедшем времени к настоящему здесь вызывает некоторые вопросы. Именно такой - и именно тут. В принципе-то мысль понятна. Как бы кончается предыстория и начинается собственно повествование от лица мальчика, почти что лирическое. Взгляд со стороны меняется взглядом изнутри. Но не любят в школе такую стилистику, увы. Не понимают.

А в целом - для школьного сочинения просто очень хорошо. Совершенно серьезно. Вот сама тема, признаться, не сближает. "Чернушка-садюшка" какая-то. Кто вас на такие ужасы вдохновил?

Все сказанное - мое личное мнение. Я далек от профессиональных знаний, еще более - от преподавания.

Comment: *Вот сама тема, признаться, не сближает.* - конец поменять, одну фразу. максимум - две.

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробный ответ, указание на ошибки и внимание в вопросу! Эта история произошла с одним из моих родственников на самом деле, написана ко дню победы по теме: "Родственники на войне".

Comment: @AnnysJuly  да дело ж не в том, произошла или нет, а в излишнем "натурализме" изложения. Ответ мрй не подробный, это я по верхам пробежался. На "подробный" у меня пороху не хватит.